# Python 3.2 print( end='') error

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I'm a born again amateur programming novice trying to learn Python 3 (3.2) using Geany on Linux. I've been trying to rework the following example in [Swaroop C H's Python 3 tutorial](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python_en%3aInput_Output#Files) My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Filename: poem.py

poem = '''\
Programming is fun 
When the work is done 
if you wanna make your work also fun: 
    use Python!
'''

with open('poem.txt', mode = 'w') as pfile:
    pfile.write(poem)

with open('poem.txt', mode = 'r') as pfile:
    while True:
        line = pfile.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        print(line, end='')
```

I can't compile the program. I get the following error which I don't understand:

```
SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('poem.py', 19, 24, "        print(line, end='')\n"))
```

I get the same error when running his code unchanged. It works fine once I remove `end=' '`. If I omit it a blank line is printed between every line of the poem.

I'd be grateful for any help/explanation.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're using Python 3? Have you tried to run it as `python3 poem.py`?

Comment: Btw., this tutorial's author seems to be a novice (as well as a terrible poet :p). The Pythonic way to iterate over the lines of a file is `for line in pfile`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have Python 3.x installed, or are not using it. This runs fine for me under Python 3.x, but I get the error you have under Python 2.x. Shebangs are not a guarentee, they have to be honoured by whatever you are using to run the script, and if you run the interpreter directly, will be ignored. So try making sure you are running Python3. Depending on your environment, this might be done in different ways, but under Unix, try `python3` instead of `python` (although some distros like Arch Linux map `python` to Python 3.x and `python2` to Python 2.x).

On a different note, all files are iterables in Python, so you are much better off doing:

```
with open('poem.txt', mode='r') as pfile:
    for line in pfile:
        print(line, end='')
```

Also note PEP8 suggests:

> Don't use spaces around the '=' sign when used to indicate a keyword argument or a default parameter value.

As in your mode arguments.

Comment: Why not just do do:

    `for line in open('poem.txt'):
        print(line, end='')`

Comment: @ccpizza: The ``with`` statement handles closing the file correctly, so it is more resilient than your example.

Comment: Thanks you were right. I had Geany configured to use Python 2. Changed the settings and it's all good. I'll bear in mind what you said about the code as well. I haven't worked out how to accept an answer yet but will do this as soon as I have.

Comment: @Disnami http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 - You might want to consider accepting Greg Hewgil's answer though, I think it's a clearer answer than mine, and so more useful for others coming across your question.

Comment: @Lattyware: As far as I understand, in my example the file would be closed automatically when the loop is done. I am curious to see a use case where `with` would work cleaner than the plain old `open`. Could you please provide an example or a link?

Comment: @ccpizza Say you open the file, begin your loop, and then there is an exception. The ``with`` statement does a ``finally`` block which cleans up the open file, while your example will not.

Comment: @Lattyware: Now I see, thanks! Having looked through the docs it has logically expanded into some sort of try/except wrapper with a cleanup block in its `__exit__` handler. Makes sense.

Comment: @ccpizza Also, not all Python implementations close the file immediately.

Answer (score 11):

Your file contains a correct "shebang" line for Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

However, in order for this shebang line to take effect, you must run your script directly as:

```
./poem.py
```

(You may have to do `chmod +x poem.py` to make the script executable.)

If you choose to explicitly run the Python interpreter:

```
python poem.py
```

then the `python` that gets run will be the first one in your PATH (type `python --version` to see which one that is). You can still run Python 3 explicitly with:

```
python3 poem.py
```

which should work for you.

Comment: +1 This is a clearer answer than mine for the main problem, but I'll leave mine up with the off-topic notes about the code at hand.